# No resource found that matches the given name even though it exist

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

I have an android relative layout

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.my.view.text.MyTextView
        style="@style/textOnBg"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/SkipIcon2"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/SkipIcon2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/signup_skip_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

how come I get this error:

`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toLeftOf' with value '@id/
 SkipIcon2').`

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

It's `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/SkipIcon2"`  you missed the `@+id`

```
 <com.my.view.text.MyTextView
        style="@style/textOnBg"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/SkipIcon2"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
```

Well, it depends on the context, when you're using the XML attribute of `android:id`, then you're specifying a new `id`, and are instructing the parser (or call it the builder) to create a new entry in `R.java`, thus you have to include a `+` sign.

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to use an id that is not already declared inside R.id. You can inter switch your views or

```
<com.my.view.text.MyTextView
    style="@style/textOnBg"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/SkipIcon2"
    android:text="Skip"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@id/SkipIcon2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/signup_skip_icon" />
```

Since the id are final and static you could be sure that it will be initialised only once

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing SkipIcon2 before it has been declared. Change the reference to

```
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/SkipIcon2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 @+id/SkipIcon2
```

instead of

```
@id/SkipIcon2
```